# How do I format timestamp in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array like this:

```
const myArray = [
    { title: "one", location: "one", start_date_time: "2023-06-28T08:47:00.000Z" },
    { title: "two", location: "two", start_date_time: "2023-06-28T08:47:00.000Z" }
]
```

I need the each objects start date to be formatted into something more readable, while maintaining the arrays structure. Something like "yyyy MM dd hh:mm", so removing dashes, the T, and the seconds.

How do I either update my existing array with formatted date and time, or create a new array with the correct formatting?

Comment: *laughs in moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Jamiec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76572064/4717491)'s answer was almost perfect but missing the removal of the time after minutes, so just added a .slice().

```js
const myArray = [
    { title: "one", location: "one", start_date_time: "2023-06-28T08:47:00.000Z" },
    { title: "two", location: "two", start_date_time: "2023-06-28T08:47:00.000Z" }
]

const result = myArray.map(x => ({
  ...x, 
  start_date_time: x.start_date_time.replaceAll("-"," ").replaceAll("T"," ").slice(0, x.start_date_time.length - 8)
 }));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply just find and replace.

```js
const myArray = [
    { title: "one", location: "one", start_date_time: "2023-06-28T08:47:00.000Z" },
    { title: "two", location: "two", start_date_time: "2023-06-28T08:47:00.000Z" }
]

const result = myArray.map(x => ({
  ...x, 
  start_date_time: x.start_date_time.replaceAll("-"," ").replaceAll("T"," ")
 }));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is a way of doing it with native javascript :

```
const myArray = [
  {
    title: "one",
    location: "one",
    start_date_time: "2023-06-28T08:47:00.000Z"
  },
  { title: "two", location: "two", start_date_time: "2023-06-28T08:47:00.000Z" }
];

const options = {
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
  year: "numeric",
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  timeZone: "UTC"
};

const formattedArray = myArray.map((el) => ({
  ...el,
  start_date_time: new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fr-FR", options)
    .format(new Date(el.start_date_time))
    .replaceAll("/", " ")
}));

console.log(formattedArray);
```

here is a working sand box https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-flower-cqdqr3?file=/src/index.js:0-556